# ruby does not use TLS1.0

Tags: ruby, curl, openssl, tls1.2

I'm working on macOS `Big Sur 11.5.2`, and I'm running a ruby server. I'm now getting a SSL connect error when I'm trying to connect to an api. I believe this is because for whatever reason ruby uses TLSv1.0 handshake instead of v1.2 or v1.3.

During the connection I'm logging what happens and get this:

```
Calling API: MyApi.get_something ...
  Trying [IP_ADDRESS]...
Connected to xxx.myapi.xxx ([IP_ADDRESS]) port 443 (#1)
Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
qa5N?+?k
?#Έ0??e?5{Q?5\nߗ;?985
???32/?.*(%xxx.myapi.xxxUnknown SSL protocol error in connection to xxx.myapi.xxx:443 
Closing connection 1
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url=https://xxx.myapi.xxx response_code=0 return_code=ssl_connect_error total_time=0.096385
HTTP response body ~BEGIN~

~END~

Exception when calling MyApi->get_something: SSL connect error
HTTP status code: 0
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 240ms (ActiveRecord: 100.9ms)
```

I uninstalled curl and openssl and rebuild rvm multiple times but without success.

curl version:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.78.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.4.0) libcurl/7.78.0 (SecureTransport) OpenSSL/1.1.1l zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.0 libidn2/2.3.2 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.44.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.7
Release-Date: 2021-07-21
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

openssl:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
```

curl is able to start TLSv1.2 connections, when I run `curl --tlsv1.2 https://bolmaster2.com` I do get the website.

Anyone an idea? Working on this for 1.5 days and don't know what else to do

Comment: Can you show us your code? What have you tried in your code to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like curl is the problem here as it seems to work, at least when used outside of ruby. What API are you trying to connect to? I.e., what is the real value of `xxx.myapi.xxx` in your ruby code? I suspect it's that HTTP endpoint that's only supports TLSv1.0... Or do you specify with your client lib (ethon?) to only use TLSv1.0?

What is the output of this ruby code?

```rb
require "ethon"
# Checks which curl version ethon lib uses...
puts Ethon::Curl.version
easy = Ethon::Easy.new(url: "https://bolmaster2.com")
easy.perform
puts easy.response_code
```